# Changing the deferred when returning it?

Tags: jquery

I've taken the following code from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise):

```
function asyncEvent() {
  var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

  // Resolve after a random interval
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
  }, Math.floor( 400 + Math.random() * 2000 ) );

  // Reject after a random interval
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.reject( "sorry" );
  }, Math.floor( 400 + Math.random() * 2000 ) );

  // Show a "working..." message every half-second
  setTimeout(function working() {
    if ( dfd.state() === "pending" ) {
      dfd.notify( "working... " );
      setTimeout( working, 500 );
    }
  }, 1 );

  // Return the Promise so caller can't change the Deferred
  return dfd.promise();
}

// Attach a done, fail, and progress handler for the asyncEvent
$.when( asyncEvent() ).then(
  function( status ) {
    alert( status + ", things are going well" );
  },
  function( status ) {
    alert( status + ", you fail this time" );
  },
  function( status ) {
    $( "body" ).append( status );
  }
);
```

I'm very noob at understanding the deferred's promise with the line:

```
 // Return the Promise so caller can't change the Deferred
return dfd.promise();
```

Okay, I understood we can't change the resolve or reject property of the Deferred object.

But using `return dfd` than `return dfd.promise()` caller can change the deferred object. I couldn't find in the wild. Can you please give an example (A clear concept) if I return deferred instead (just to know about it properly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

If you use `return dfd` instead of `return dfd.promise()`, the caller can actually change the state promise.

Means the caller can call `resolve`, `reject`, `notify`, `resolveWith`, `rejectWith`, and `notifyWith` on the returned `dfd` object to change the state of Deffered object.

By doing `return dfd.promise()` you are avoiding call from doing that. This fits for the scenario for which you don't want to change the state of `Deferred object` by caller function.

---

## Example

```
function asyncEvent() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    // Resolve after a random interval
    setTimeout(function () {
        dfd.resolve("hurray");
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 2000));

    // Reject after a random interval
    setTimeout(function () {
        dfd.reject("sorry");
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 2000));

    // Show a "working..." message every half-second
    setTimeout(function working() {
        if (dfd.state() === "pending") {
            dfd.notify("working... ");
            setTimeout(working, 500);
        }
    }, 1);

    // Return the Promise so caller can't change the Deferred
    return dfd;
}


// Attach a done, fail, and progress handler for the asyncEvent
$.when(asyncEvent().reject("sorry")).then(

function (status) {
    alert(status + ", things are going well");
},

function (status) {
    alert(status + ", you fail this time");
},

function (status) {
    $("body").append(status);
});
```

In this example, instead of returning `dfd.promise()` I am returning `dfd` object. And then I am rejecting it directly when it is called under `$.when`

---

## JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8mbgzrkn/1/

---

If you change the `asyncEvent()` function to return `return dfd.promise();` and execute same code again, you will surely get an error as undefined is not a function on that line

[image: promise error]

Comment: Changed answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

jQuery appear to have removed exposing `resolve, reject, notify, resolveWith, rejectWith`, and `notifyWith` methods within `.then` at most recent version ; though still exposed at `1.7.2` http://jsfiddle.net/8mbgzrkn , http://jsfiddle.net/8mbgzrkn/1

```
var fn = function() {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  dfd.resolve(1);
  return dfd
};

var res = fn().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data, this);
  //this.resolve(2);
  return this
});

res.then(function(deferred) {
  console.log(deferred)
});
```